# __bridge not needed for method arguments?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, bridge

As we know, with ARC we need a `__bridge` to convert an id to a `void *`:

```
void *t = (void *)self;           // ERROR: Cast of ... requires a bridged cast
void *t = (__bridge void *)self;  // CORRECT
```

So are C function calls:

```
void f(void *t) {
  ....
}

f((void *)self);           // ERROR
f((__bridge void *)self);  // CORRECT
```

I think this should hold for methods as well, and indeed this [Beginning ARC in iOS 5 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5773/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2) gives the following example, and says that the `__bridge` is needed:

```
MyClass *myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(__bridge void *)myObject];
```

However, today I accidentally dropped a `__bridge` in a method call in one of my programs, and the code compiled and ran without any issue. The `__bridge` in the above sample seems to be unnecessary:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(void *)myObject];  // COMPILED OK
```

Is this right? Is the `__bridge` really unnecessary in this case? Or removing it changes what the code means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered in the [ARC docs section 3.3.3](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#conversion-from-retainable-object-pointer-type-in-certain-contexts) (emphasis mine):

> 3.3.3 Conversion from retainable object pointer type in certain contexts
>
> [beginning Apple 4.0, LLVM 3.1]
>
> If an expression of retainable object pointer type is explicitly cast
>   to a C retainable pointer type, the program is ill-formed as discussed
>   above unless the result is immediately used:
>
> - **to initialize a parameter in an Objective-C message send where the
>     parameter is not marked with the cf_consumed attribute, or to**
> - initialize a parameter in a direct call to an audited function where
>     the parameter is not marked with the cf_consumed attribute.

In your code, `myObject` is a "retainable object pointer." A "C retainable pointer type" include `void*` (this is a slightly sloppy definition that they're using as a placeholder because Core Foundation "objects" are often `void*`).

So an ObjC object can be implicitly converted to a `void*` if used as a method parameter. In that case, there are no additional memory management semantics (i.e. it is the equivalent of a `__bridge` cast). [Section 7.8](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#c-retainable-pointer-types) warns us that `void*` may not be treated this way in the future, but I wouldn't worry about that. If it happens, adding the `__bridge` will be trivial.

The one thing to keep in mind is that `myObject` is not protected here. It is up to you to make sure it is retained some other way until the animations complete, or you may crash.

Comment: Very interesting, and well spotted. +1 because you gave me yet another reason to hate ARC ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`__bridge` is used for passing ownership of variables/references (Like retain count) which is C api to objective-C or objective-C to API.

Go through [Clang's doc](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#bridged-casts):

> Bridged casts
>
> A bridged cast is a C-style cast annotated with one of three keywords:
>
> ```
> (__bridge T) op casts the operand to the destination type T. If T is a retainable object pointer type, then op must have a
> ```
>
> non-retainable pointer type. If T is a non-retainable pointer type,
>   then op must have a retainable object pointer type. Otherwise the cast
>   is ill-formed. There is no transfer of ownership, and ARC inserts no
>   retain operations.
>       (__bridge_retained T) op casts the operand, which must have retainable object pointer type, to the destination type, which must be
>   a non-retainable pointer type. ARC retains the value, subject to the
>   usual optimizations on local values, and the recipient is responsible
>   for balancing that +1.
>       (__bridge_transfer T) op casts the operand, which must have non-retainable pointer type, to the destination type, which must be a
>   retainable object pointer type. ARC will release the value at the end
>   of the enclosing full-expression, subject to the usual optimizations
>   on local values.
>
> These casts are required in order to transfer objects in and out of
>   ARC control; see the rationale in the section on conversion of
>   retainable object pointers.
>
> Using a __bridge_retained or __bridge_transfer cast purely to convince
>   ARC to emit an unbalanced retain or release, respectively, is poor
>   form.

Now,

**void *t = (void *)self;**           // ERROR: Cast of ... requires a bridged cast
Why it wrong because you trying to casting reference from Objective-C to C. It failed to pass ownership of reference.

**void *t = (__bridge void *)self;**  // CORRECT
Why it correct because to transfer your objective-C reference to C. According to doc of LLVM. See above given casting rules.

```
MyClass *myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(__bridge void *)myObject];
```

Above lines are completely still ok because you pass C reference type context instead of `NULL`